# How can I fix pip3 issue in Windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, installation, pip

I want to install matplotlib. However i got this error:

> pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
> that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1

- pip3 install matplotlib
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I checked the path of Python but couldn't find anything else about the problem. I added the path environment variable manually also. How can I fix it?

python : python 3.10.2 version

Answer (score 0):

On windows, use `pip` instead of `pip3`.

If you want to install matplotlib, use command `pip install matplotlib`.

Answer (score 0):

That mean you don’t have pip3 installed or pip3 is not in your path variable.
You can try `python3 -m pip install <whatever>`
or just add pip3 into your path manually